# Android checkbox in Listview getting false when I select a checkbox in ICS?

Tags: android

I have a listview with some check boxes its a simple_multiple_listitem view. This is  how I am initializing my listview

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                            subcatNamesList));
```

On loading of list I need to show some checkboxes as selected I have done this by using below code

```
for (int i = 0; i < subCatArrayLlist.size(); i++) {

                        for (int j = 0; j < selectedItemsList.size(); j++) {
                            if (subCatArrayLlist.get(i).getSubCatSrNo()
                                    .contains(selectedItemsList.get(j))) {
                                listView.setItemChecked(i, true);
                            }


                        }
```

I also need to get the state of check boxes when I select or deselect after loading the list, I write some code for that which work perfectly on jellybeans [means when I select check box it's give me true and false on deselection]. But in ICS it's giving me all opposite why this is happening please look into my problem I really stuck at this part.
Below is my mcode which I am using for selection and deselection.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int pos, long arg3) {
                            System.out.println("Get item at position= "
                                    + listView.getChildAt(pos));

                            // selectedItemsList.add(subCatArrayLlist.get(pos)
                            // .getSubCatSrNo());

                            CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) arg1
                                    .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                            System.out.println("State of check Box= "
                                    + ctv.isChecked());


                            if (ctv.isChecked() == true) {
                                selectedItemsList.add(subCatArrayLlist.get(pos)
                                        .getSubCatSrNo());
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Cat Selected",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            if (ctv.isChecked() == false) {
                                selectedItemsList.remove(subCatArrayLlist.get(
                                        pos).getSubCatSrNo());

                                Toast.makeText(context, "Cat DeSelected",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not checked this in ICS but you could implement onCheckChange in your Activity. This removes the need for using the adapter to get the item and then edit your list. Sample code:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        int pos = mMainListView.getPositionForView(buttonView);

        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            String item = mAllItems.get(pos);        

            if (isChecked) {
                mSelectedItems.add(item);
            } else {
                mSelectedItems.remove(item);
            }
        }
}
```